# cannot find windows cmdlet

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I am using Windows 7 as well as windows 2008 r2,  I am trying to write a powershell script to find all the software installed on all the machines on my network.  I have done research and see the cmdlets I need to do this task but I get some many unrecognized cmdlts.  I am new to powershell and the other admins only use GUI's and I am trying to show them how powerful the command line can be.  Is there something I need to run to update my machine with the latest cmdlets?

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

currently the command that is failing is Get-RemoteProgram

I am using 64-bit machines

Comment: `Get-RemoteProgram`: The term 'Get-RemoteProgram' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. You need to perform something like `Import-Module` once before using it…

Comment: Is this the Get-RemoteProgram you are trying to use: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RemoteProgram-Get-list-de9fd2b4 ?

Comment: Tony, yes it is...  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-RemoteProgram-Get-list-de9fd2b4)Get-RemoteProgram, you need to "dot source" it before you can use the command.  This tells your script to read the file and include the functions it contains in your script.

> . .\Get-RemoteProgram.ps1
>
> Load the function into memory by dot-sourcing the script file this makes the Get-RemoteProgram function available in your current session of PowerShell

So your script would need to include

```
 . .\Get-RemoteProgram.ps1
```

prior to any call to `Get-RemoteProgram`

As far as the version of PowerShell, 3.0 is certinaly not the latest.  You can always find the latest version at Microsoft.  Currently, https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell is a good place to reference, or even check Wikipedia--lots of places are kept updated with the latest info on PowerShell.